# ¿Por qué me imprime dos veces esto en React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código donde estoy llevando cada componente a su mínima expresión, en este caso un formulario de registro, el cuál quiero generar dependiendo de los parámetros que le mande, en este caso tengo en un archivo propiedades donde tengo los campos que tendrá un Usuario. Esos parámetros se los mandó a un componente Registro, el cuál contiene un componente formulario y este tendrá varios inputs dependiendo de los parametros que reciba, de manera que si tengo otros registros pueda reutilizar estos mismos. Ahora no se si lo que estoy haciendo esta bien, pero de momento, haciendo una sencilla prueba cuando llamó a dichos componentes, se me está imprimiendo un mensaje en consola dos veces y solo estoy llamando una vez a dichos componentes, y no se si esto pueda afectar de alguna forma el resultado final.

Archivo index.js que llama a mi App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Archivo App.js que llama a RegistrarUsuario que pertenece a Usuario.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Registrar as RegistrarUsuario} from './Usuario/Registrar';
import {CamposUsuario} from './Usuario/Propiedades';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <RegistrarUsuario {...CamposUsuario}/>
   </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Archivo Registrar.js que llama a Formulario.js, aquí es donde imprimo en consola y me imprime dos veces.

```
import React,{Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import {Formulario} from '../Componentes/Formulario/Formulario';

export class Registrar extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={...props};
   };
   render(){
      const campos=this.props;
      console.log(campos,"registrar usuario");
      return(
     <Fragment>
     <h1>Usuario</h1>
     </Fragment>
      );
   };
};
```

Archivo Formulario.js donde incluiría los inputs pero de momento no tengo nada ahi.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Input from '../Subcomponentes/Input';

export default class Formulario extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={...props};
   };
   render(){
      const campos=this.props;
      return(
     <div>
        Hola inmundo
     </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Y en Consola me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchos hacen la misma pregunta, y lo que pasa es que el el funcionamiento normal de react.

Comment: Estas utilizando <React.StrictMode> al inicializar tu aplicación?

Comment: Podias usar `React.memo` en tus componentes hijos, para que solo hagan un re-render cuando los props hayan cambiado. Otra cosa, es que no tienes que poner los props a `this.state`, eso esta de mas, simplemete usa los props.

Comment: @JesusOchoa si, al principio está esa parte

Comment: @Isaac ok, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: @soyunewok te recomiendo la siguiente lectura, explican a alto nivel el por que pasa https://medium.com/@andreasheissenberger/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625

Comment: @JesusOchoa gracias

Comment: En el index.js comenta las lineas de <React.StrictMode>